# Automatic merge is happing with developers and maintainers permission in Gitlab-CE

Tags: git, gitlab

I am exploring Gitlabs features to replace our existing system which is internal git server along with gerrit.

I have created a group called dev with three users: User A, User B and an admin.

I have created a project `testproject` which is default master branch which is protected added dev group to that project.

In the project repository settings I have added these permissions:

(master branch, protected with Allowed to push developers+maintainers, Allowed to merge Maintainers)

I clone the project with User A who has developer permissions, added new changes and pushed the changes using `git push -u origin master`.

It does not show option to create merge request, it is directly merged and showed as merge commit.

My usecase is  developer should not be allowed to merge, only Project maintainer should be allowed.

Comment: To forbidden developers `Allow to push` to master branch.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to set the `master` branch to protected, allowed to push only to maintainers, and allowed to merge to only maintainers. (For some projects I also set so that maintainers cannot push either, as a protection against accidentally pushing to the `master` branch.)

Your developers will then have to use another branch then `master`, for example `feature-branch-1`. After they have pushed this branch, they will be able to create a merge request from `feature-branch-1` to `master`.

Comment: Ok thanks, so ideally its not best practice to allow devlopers to directly push to branch